# Can I have different widths for different tr elements in the same table

Tags: css, html-table, width

As the title, I'd like to set different widths for different TRs in a table. 
Is it possible?

```
[--------tr.trheader > td--------]
   [---------tr > td---------]
   [---------tr > td---------]
   [---------tr > td---------]
   [---------tr > td---------]
[--------tr.trheader > td--------]
   [---------tr > td---------]
   [---------tr > td---------]
```

I solved in this way

```
...
        <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="padding"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>blabla</td>
                        <td>bla bla bla</td>
                        <td class="padding"></td>
                    </tr>
        </thead>

...
```

Using ".padding" empty with a little width.

Comment: *must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* ... what have you tried?

Comment: Is not enough "different widths for different TRs" in the same table???

Comment: I don't understand why these negative votes, when it's because of the people that don't grasp the question o.O

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need tables within the main table.